# Lime/bath stone - In need of clean and repair

Tags: stone, limestone

The stone on my house which I think is Bath stone or Limestone is getting dirty. I’m not sure if it’s pollution, acid rain or something else.

I tried to give it a quick scrub with water and a gentle soap but I didn’t have any luck.

Can anyone tell me the type of cleaning agents that might be able to help or if this needs something more extensive?

[pic](https://ibb.co/tHvNMZn)
[pic2](https://ibb.co/JC13Wyj)

Comment: Could you provide a photo? I have done a lot of historic home renovations  and do not remember ever seeing limestone used other than cut blocks for foundations. Is it outside ? Sorry I did not see the picture, that looks more like concrete with a scratch coat covering to me. The discoloration possibly iron in the water.

Comment: I think "bath" stone means limestone from near Bath , UK.  I would clean it with any acid and a stainless brush. The acid will dissolve the limestone so be judicious.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience of cleaning this stone, but I do recommend caution using any products you might find yourself.

Cleaning this type of stone is a likely to be specialist job, especially on a historic building. There is a risk of damaging the face of the stone and any work you carry out might be restricted by local regulations for listed buildings, conservation areas etc.

https://beta.bathnes.gov.uk/sites/default/files/2020-01/clean_bath_stone_0.pdf

https://borealabode.com/bath-stone-cleaning-repair